# The definiton of a multiplier on a Banach algebra

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. Some textbooks define a (left ) multiplier as a map $T:A\rightarrow A$ satisfying $T(ab)=T(a)b$ for all $a,b\in A$ and assume that $A$ needs to be a without order Banach algebra, that is, if $xA=(0)$ for some $x\in A$, then $x=0$. (right multiplier is defined in a similar way). However, some other define a (left) multiplier as a linear map (even continuous) on  a (general) Banach algebra satisfying the above condition. Am I missing something here? I know the first definition does not assume that $T$ is linear however it follows from that $A$ is without order.
Is a multiplier assumed to be continuous by definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be interested to know *exactly* what sources you are using, as any standard textbook does prove the following.

I actually don't know what happens for just a left multiplier (though also do not know any counter-examples off the top of my head), but suppose we have a *double multiplier* $(L,R)$, that is, $L$ is a left multiplier, and $R$ is a right multiplier, and $R(a)b = aL(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$.

Notice that being "without order" is equivalent to:

> For $a,b\in A$, if $ac=bc$ for all $c\in A$, then $a=b$.

There is an obvious equivalent definition on the other side.  I will assume **both** these conditions hold for $A$.

Using this, we find that for $a,b\in A$ and $\lambda$ a scalar,
$$ c(L(a)+\lambda L(b)) = cL(a) + c (\lambda L(b))
= R(c)a + R(c) (\lambda b) = R(c)(a+\lambda b) = cL(a+\lambda b), $$
for any $c\in A$, and thus $L$ is linear.  Similarly $R$ is linear.  In fact, it is enough that $R(a)b=aL(b)$ for $a,b\in A$; then a similar argument shows that $L$ is automatically a left multiplier, and $R$ a right multiplier.

We don't assume that $L$ and $R$ are bounded.  However, we can use the closed graph theorem in the following way: if $(a_n)\rightarrow 0$ and $L(a_n)\rightarrow a$, then
$$ ba = \lim_n bL(a_n) = \lim_n R(b) a_n = 0 $$
for any $b$, and so $a=0$, and thus $L$ is continuous; similarly $R$ is continuous.

Comment: Question about the literature: it seems from a quick search online that the terminology "without order" is mostly used in the commutative setting, and the phrase doesn't seem to appear in the Big Book of Dales. Do you know any sources which use "without order" in the 2-sided noncommutative setting?

Comment: @YemonChoi: I think you are quite correct.  I was merely copying the terminology the Questioner used; I have not seen "without order" myself.  Barry Johnson used the term "faithful" which seems reasonable; I _think_ I've also seen "non-degenerate" used (both these terms are of course a little overused in Mathematics).

Comment: @MatthewDaws What happens if we define a multiplier on a Banach algebra $A$ as a linear function satisfying $T(a)b=aT(b)$?($A$ is not necessarily faithful). In Kaniuth's
A course in commutative Banach algebras, p. 27, it is defined only on faithful Banach algebras.

Comment: @Fermat: The word to look at is "commutative"!  If $A$ is _commutative_ and $T(ab)=aT(b)$ then let $L=R=T$.  Then $R(a)b = T(a)b = bT(a) = T(ba) = T(ab) = aT(b) = aL(b)$ and so $(L,R)$ is a double multiplier, as I indicate.

Comment: @YemonChoi You are right and as mentioned by MathhewDaws faithful is a more standard term. However, my question is why don't we define a multiplier on a general Banach algebra as a linear mapping (not necessarily continuous). which satisfies the above condition? The sources, i have seen, define multipliers only on faithful Banach algebras and then deduce the linearity and continuity from faithfulness. But

Comment: Kaniuth's Fourier and Fourier-Stieltjes Algebras on Locally Compact Groups book, p. 5, says : "A linear operator  $T:A\rightarrow A$  of a commutative Banach algebra $A$ is called a multiplier if $T(ab)=aT(b)$ holds for all $a,b\in A$".

Comment: @Fermat: As I say in my answer, I don't know!  I suspect there is a counter-example, but I'm afraid I don't know of one.

Comment: @MatthewDaws I think what causes confusion is the difference between the  notions of "multiplier" and "double mutiplier". The second one, is defined as in your above comment. (and your answer). But some books or papers define a multiplier as an operator $T:A\rightarrow A$ for which   $T(a)b=aT(b)$ (not necessarily equal to $T(ab)$). Is it possible to define a multiplier as a linear mapping $T:A\rightarrow A$ satisfying $T(a)b=aT(b)$ for an arbitrary Banach algebra?

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thank you very much, I am sorry for consecutive questions.

Comment: @Fermat: Studying $T(a)b=aT(b)$ is not very interesting: for any $a$ with have $T(a)a=aT(a)$ so always $a$ and $T(a)$ commute.  Also $eT(abc)d = T(e)abcd = eT(ab)cd = eabT(c)d = eaT(b)cd$ so if $A$ is left/right faithful then $T(abc)=aT(b)c$ so $T$ is a bimodule map.  But then $T(abc)=aT(b)c$ commutes with $abc$, which starts to look like a very strong condition.  (Unless, of course, $A$ is commutative...)